# Solution to Inviscid Burger's equation given piecewise initial condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

I'm taking Non-Linear PDEs course this semester. I'm stuck in this HW problem.

Solve the IVP:

$ u_t+uu_x =0, \   \ x \in \mathbb{R}, \  t\ge 0 $

$$
u(x,0) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
& 1 &&\text{for}\; x < -1\\
& -x &&\text{for}\; {-1}\leqslant x \leqslant 0 \\
& 1 &&\text{for}\; x > 0\, .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

This is my attempt.

$\frac{du}{dt}=0$ along $\frac{dx}{dt} = u$

$\implies u = \xi$ along $x = tu_0(\xi)+\xi$

For $\xi < -1$, $u = 1$ along the characteristic $x = t+\xi$

For $\xi \in (-1,0)$, $u = -\xi$ along $x = -\xi t+\xi$ \implies $u = \frac{x}{t-1}$

For $\xi >0$, $u = 1$ along the characteristic $x = t+\xi$

Plotting these characteristics (on desmos), we can observe that there is a void. The horizontal axis is $x$, and the vertical axis is $t$.
[image]

Hence, a fan of characteristics will emerge from $(x,t) =(0,0)$. In that region $u =\frac{x}{t}$ as shown below.

[image]

For $t>1$, the fan of characteristics emerging from origin intersects the characteristics $x= -\xi t+\xi$ emerging from $-1 <x<0$. Hence, a shock would emerge. From Rankine-Hugoniot Conditions, shock speed can be calculated as:

$$\frac{ds}{dt} = \frac{u^{+}+u^{-}}{2} = \frac{\frac{s}{t}+\frac{s}{t-1}}{2}$$

On solving this ODE with the initial condition as $s(t = 1+) = 0$, we get: $s = C \sqrt{t(t-1)}$ where $C$ is an arbitrary constant. Now, here is the problem,

1. How to get $C$?
2. On plotting the shock path, another void seems to be created which doesn't seem quite right!

Can you please clarify whether my approach is correct? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: Apologies for poor formatting/images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JJacquelin's answer resolves the solution for $x<0$ and $0<t<1$. Notice that there is a rarefaction fan of the form $u = x/t$ starting at $(0,0)$, so this should also contain a condition where $u(x,t) = x/t$ for $0\leq x \leq t$ for $0\leq t\leq1$. From this and JJaacquelin's answer, we can determine that the solution at $t=1$ is given by
$$
u(x,1) = \begin{cases}
1 & x<0 \\
x & 0<x<1 \\
1 & x>1
\end{cases}.
$$
We now solve this initial value problem starting at $t=1$. We can see that a shock will occur at $x=0$, so our solution for $t>1$ will look like
$$
u(x,t) = \begin{cases}
1 & x<s(t) \\
x/t & s(t) < x < t \\
1 & x > t
\end{cases},
$$
where $x = s(t)$ is the shock curve. To find the shock curve, we apply the Rankine-Hugoniot conditions, which say
$$
s'(t) = \frac{f(u_+) - f(u_-)}{u_+ - u_-} = \frac{u_+ + u_-}{2} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{s}{2t}, \, s(1) = 0.
$$
Notice here that we substituted $u_+ = x/t$ and $x = s(t)$ to obtain this ODE. Solving obtains $s(t) = t - \sqrt{t}$. We can combine this with the $0<t<1$ solution to obtain a final solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$ u_t+uu_x =0$$
Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs :
$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{u}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $du=0$ :
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{c_1}$ :
$$c_1t-x=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_1=F(c_2)$ is :
$$\boxed{u=F(u\,t-x)}$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (To be determined according to the initial condition).

Initial condition $\quad u(x,0)=F(-x)$ :

$$
F(-x) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
& 1 &&\text{for}\; x < -1\\
& -x &&\text{for}\; {-1}\leqslant x \leqslant 0 \\
& 1 &&\text{for}\; x > 0\, 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Let $\quad X=-x$

$$
F(X) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
& 1 &&\text{for}\; -X < -1 &&\text{i.e.} && 1<X\\
& X &&\text{for}\; {-1}\leqslant -X \leqslant 0 &&\text{i.e.} && 0\leq X \leq 1\\
& 1 &&\text{for}\; -X > 0\, &&\text{i.e.} && X<0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
[image]

The function $F(X)$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where $X=u\,t-x$.

$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
& 1 &&\text{for} && 1<u\,t-x &&\text{i.e.} && 1<t-x\\
& u\,t-x &&\text{for} && 0\leq u\,t-x \leq 1 &&\text{i.e.} && 0\leq u=\frac{x}{t-1}\leq 1 \text{ and } 0<t<1\\
& 1 &&\text{for} && u\,t-x<0 &&\text{i.e.} && t-x<0
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

$$
\boxed {u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
& 1 &&\text{for} && x<t-1\\
& \frac{x}{t-1} &&\text{for} && 0\leq \frac{x}{t-1}\leq 1 \text{ and } 0<t<1\\
& 1 &&\text{for} && t<x
\end{aligned}
\right.}
$$

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JJacquelin. How can we determine the shock path using this approach?

Comment: I don't think this solution is complete, as there should be a rarefaction occuring for $x>0$ which will collide with the shock at $x=0$, $t=1$, leading to a nontrivial shock curve.

Comment: @sai saandeep . Meanwhile  whpowell96 ansewered to this question. So I have nothing to add. Moreover there is no context in the question which allows to discuss about the validity to apply or not the Rankine-Hugoniot hypothesis. Whitout knowing if there is a physical model behind the PDE one cannot say if this model is compatible or not with the Rankine-Hugoniot method to describe $u(x,t)$ for $t>1$.

Comment: That is fair but I also think one can assume that the desired solution meets these criteria since it is a homework problem and OP discusses shocks and R-H in their attempt.